# Where to put JQuery in React Component?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, material-design

I am using materialize css library in my React app.
So, I want to use "modal" from it. There are 2 ways to initialize it:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
var instances = M.Modal.init(elems, options);
 });

// Or with jQuery

$(document).ready(function(){
$('.modal').modal();
});
```

So, I usually do the 2nd way like so:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const $ = window.$;
    $('.dropdown-trigger').dropdown();
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.modal').modal();
    })
}
```

And it all worked for me, but now I have an extra method in my ComponentDidMount(), that requests to server api:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.getCurrentUser();
    const $ = window.$;
    $('.dropdown-trigger').dropdown();
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.modal').modal();
    })
}

getCurrentUser() {
    fetch('api/user/'+ localStorage.getItem("currentUser") +'/me', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    })
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                this.setState({
                    isLoadong: false,
                    failed: true
                })
            }
            else {
                response.json().then(user => {
                    this.setState({
                        user: user,
                        isLoadong: false,
                        failed: false
                    })
                });
            }
        })
}
```

So why the modal doesn't work now?
How to do it all the right way?

Comment: Don't ! Use a react material library

Comment: This is a pretty bad implementation. I'd suggest looking into react libraries that you could use. There are tons of them online!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only want to use jQuery in the leaf nodes of your React App's tree structure. If this component has any child components, this is a bad idea. If it is a leaf node component, then you will want to put your jQuery logic in the componentDidMount() function.

This page has some helpful material on the subject: https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html

Comment: Thank's! And do u have an idea why it stops working when I add this.getCurrentUser() method to componentDidMount?

Comment: Sorry, I don't. This doesn't look bad. I'd try adding a catch after your then. Something like .then(// code).catch((err) => {
    console.log('error: ' + err);
  })